# Set a property when changing to specific TODO state

Tags: org-mode

I would like to set/unset a property when entering a certain `TODO` state.

Example: Set the property `:COOKIE_DATA: todo recursive` automatically when the state is set to `PROJ`. So all the `TODO`s in project headings would be counted recursively, and not only `TODO`s which are direct children of the current tree (default).

How could this be done?

I do *not* want to set `org-hierarchical-todo-statistics` to activate recursive counting for every `TODO` globally.

Comment: Write a function to add (or delete) the property and add it to `org-after-todo-state-change-hook`. The function should check the current `TODO` state: if it is `PROJ` add the property, otherwise delete it. See the `Property API` section of the manual with `C-h i g(org)Using the Property API` for relevant functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Table of Contents

1. The answer
2. A minimal working example

## The answer

As mentioned by @NickD, you can accomplish by writing a hook.

```
(defun my/org-set-cookie-data-when-state-changes-to-proj ()
  (interactive)
  (when (equal (org-get-todo-state) "PROJ")
    (org-set-property "COOKIE_DATA" "todo recursive")))
```

```
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'my/org-set-cookie-data-when-state-changes-to-proj)
```

## A minimal working example

Consider the following minimal working exmaple

```
#+TODO: TODO(t) | DONE(d)
#+TODO: NOTPROJ(n) | PROJ(p)

* This is a heading
* This is another heading
```

After changing the states of the headings with `org-todo` (by default, bound to `C-c C-t`) , we get the following

```
#+TODO: TODO(t) | DONE(d)
#+TODO: NOTPROJ(n) | PROJ(p)

* PROJ This is a heading
:PROPERTIES:
:COOKIE_DATA: todo recursive
:END:

* DONE This is another heading
```

Comment: I don't know a lot of elisp yet, and had some reservations getting my hands wet. But this looks managable. Thank you for writing it out! How would I remove the property when changing back to "TODO"? Is there also a function for that?

Comment: Got it, its `org-delete-property`. I will try to edit the function to reset property when going back to `TODO`. -- It works :-)